# How do you block a thread until a condition becomes true?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

In Clojure, how do you block a thread (future) until a condition becomes true?  Or, alternatively, perhaps keep retrying until a condition becomes true?  This is easy when you have condition variables, but I'm not sure what's the Clojure way to do this.

To be more specific, I have a shared variable that is accessible by many futures at the same time.  A future should do the following:

1. Check the state of the variable.
2. If the state meets a certain condition, update it to a new state.
3. If the state does not meet the condition, the future should block or retry, until the condition is met (by another thread modifying the state).

Comment: I happened to look at #clojure logs and it seems that you're actually interested in a scenario where a shared resource is to be exclusively held by the thread that's using it, then returned to the "available" state for the next thread to pick up once the current thread no longer needs it. You can do that with core.async using a channel with a buffer of size 1: (1) create the channel -- `(chan 1)`, putting this where appropriate -- and put the resource on the channel; (2) use `(<!! the-channel)` to ask for exclusive hold on the resource (blocking); (3) when done, return the resource with `>!!`.

Answer (score 1):

The Java platform supports condition variables, see the documentation for [`java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

The example from the above page translates easily into Clojure:

```
;;; based on the example in java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition
;;; documentation for JDK 1.7, see the link above

(defprotocol PBoundedBuffer
  (-put [buf x])
  (-take [buf]))

(import (java.util.concurrent.locks ReentrantLock Condition))

(deftype BoundedBuffer [^ReentrantLock lock
                        ^Condition not-full?
                        ^Condition not-empty?
                        ^objects items
                        ^:unsynchronized-mutable ^int putptr
                        ^:unsynchronized-mutable ^int takeptr
                        ^:unsynchronized-mutable ^int cnt]
  PBoundedBuffer
  (-put [buf x]
    (.lock lock)
    (try
      (while (== cnt (alength items))
        (.await not-full?))
      (aset items putptr x)
      (set! putptr (unchecked-inc-int putptr))
      (if (== putptr (alength items))
        (set! putptr (int 0)))
      (set! cnt (unchecked-inc-int cnt))
      (.signal not-empty?)
      (finally
        (.unlock lock))))

  (-take [buf]
    (.lock lock)
    (try
      (while (zero? cnt)
        (.await not-empty?))
      (let [x (aget items takeptr)]
        (set! takeptr (unchecked-inc-int takeptr))
        (if (== takeptr (alength items))
          (set! takeptr (int 0)))
        (set! cnt (unchecked-dec-int cnt))
        (.signal not-full?)
        x)
      (finally
        (.unlock lock)))))

(defn bounded-buffer [capacity]
  (let [lock (java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.)]
    (BoundedBuffer. lock
                    (.newCondition lock)
                    (.newCondition lock)
                    (object-array capacity)
                    0
                    0
                    0)))
```

A test drive at the REPL:

```
(def bb (bounded-buffer 3))

(-put bb 1)
(-put bb 2)
(-put bb 3)

(future (-put bb 4) (println :foo))

(-take bb)
```

As desired, the future blocks, then prints `:foo` after the final call to `-take`.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure provides [refs](http://clojure.org/refs), [agents](http://clojure.org/agents) and [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) for this kind of problem, and it sounds like you could use refs if your problem doesn't have any side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the condition or value you're checking in an agent, and add a watch that performs the desired actions once the condition becomes `true` or the value is the value you want:

```
(def x (agent 0))

(defn do-this-once-x-is-10 [key agnt old-val new-val]
  (when (= new-val 10)
    (println "x is now 10")))

(add-watch x :print-alert do-this-once-x-is-10)

(dotimes [_ 10]
  (Thread/sleep 1000)
  (send x inc))

; the value stored in x is incremented every second; after 10 seconds,
; the value of x will equal 10 and "x is now 10" will print
```